# PHP unable to echo the text after a condition is met

Tags: php

I am not getting the desired result from the code below. Everything works fine But there is one main problem:

1. When there is no song in the database it shows empty result just with back button. It fails to show echo 'Sorry! This song is not available on our database.';

I cant figure out where the mistake is. So plz help.

Thanks in advance!!!

```
<?php

// Php code that fetches audio from the database in server and shows the audio files with singers available for the submitted data

// In submission page DROPDOWN consists of Playlist name and TEXTBOX allows to type the song number for that playlist.

// Standard format for the audio file stored in the databse is Songnumber-Playlistname-Singer's Shortname.mp3

// MP3 files will be inside the AUDIO folder and this PHP code runs from the root folder where there is index.html file for data submission.



// Valid song Numbers of Each Playlists that user choose
$validsongnumbers = [
    'Rock' => 3, 
    'Pop' => 5, 
    'Jazz' => 6
];

// Data captured from dropdown submitted by a user in homepage 
$PlaylistName = $_POST['Dropdown'];
$songNumber = $_POST['songnumber'];

// Check the playlist exists
if (!array_key_exists($PlaylistName, $validsongnumbers)) {
    echo 'Invalid playlist provided.';
    exit;
}

// Check the song number is not greater than what is allowed
if ((int)$songNumber > $validsongnumbers[$PlaylistName]) {
    echo  'Invalid song number provided.';
    exit;
}


$userselectedsong=sprintf('%s-%s', $songNumber, $PlaylistName );
$audiofilelocation = 'audio/' .$userselectedsong. ".mp3";

 // check for user entered song in entire audio folder
$files = glob("audio/" .$userselectedsong. "*.{mp3,wav,wma,mp4}", GLOB_BRACE);
$count= count ($files);
if ($count == 0) {
  echo '<span style="color: red;"/>Sorry! This song is not available on our database.</span>'; //Why this part is not wotking??? Rest all is ok
}else
    $arr=outputFiles( $audiofilelocation , $userselectedsong );
foreach( $arr as $obj ) {
    printf(
        '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="audio/css/main.css"><div class="wrap-login100 p-l-85 p-r-85 p-t-55 p-b-55"><br><br><audio width="100%" height="100%" controls="controls" src="%1$s" controlslist="nodownload" type="audio/mp3" style="visibility: visible;">
</audio><br /><font size="4" color="#000080"><b>Singer : <font size="4" color="#B22222">%2$s<br></b></font></font></div>',
        $obj->file,
        $obj->name
                );
                
        }       

function singeractualname( $ssn ) {
    switch( $ssn ){
        case 'RI':return 'Rihanna';
        case 'MJ':return 'Michael Jackson';
        default:return 'Singer name not available !!!';
    }
}
function outputFiles( $path, $song ){
    $output=[];
    if( file_Exists( $path ) ){
        $dirItr=new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $path, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::KEY_AS_PATHNAME );
        
        foreach( new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $dirItr, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST ) as $obj => $info ) {
            if( $info->isFile() ){
                
                $pttn=sprintf( '@%s-\w+\.\w+@i', $song );
                preg_match( $pttn, $info->getFileName(), $col );

                if( !empty( $col ) ){
                    foreach( $col as $file ){
                        
                        $ext=pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
                        list( $int, $cat, $code )=explode( '-', pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_FILENAME ) );
                        
                        $output[]=(object)[
                            'ext'       =>  $ext,
                            'code'      =>  $code,
                            'name'      =>  singeractualname( $code ),
                            'file'      =>  'audio/' . $info->getFileName(),
                            'index'     =>  $int,
                            'category'  =>  $cat
                        ];                          
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: when you `print_r($count)`, what is the result? is its result is 0?

Comment: What is the debug result of $files right before your check?

Comment: Result is 12 not 0

Comment: when you try it   `echo '<span style="color: red;"/>Sorry! This song is not available on our database.</span>';`, whats the result? blank? or error?

Comment: if the `$count` is 12, it will never show the echo. Please try with result 0.

Comment: when i print $files it says ----> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\music\search.php on line 46
Array

Comment: The you are using echo? Use print_r or var_dump. The result is the files that are found, if count is currently 12 the glob is finding 12 files at the moment.

Comment: Abed Putra when run alone it gives (Sorry! This song is not available on our database.) in red color but when kept inside code it gives blank dont know why???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have doubled "if if":

```
if if(count($files) < 0
```

Second, number of files can never be negative. You should compare if number is equal 0 (zero), not less than 0.

UPDATE:

Still wrong code:

```
if ($count=0)
```

This is not comparison, but assignment. You are giving $count value 0. For comparison you must use:

```
if ($count == 0)
```

Comment: i have corrected the code but still there is a problem. Plz have a look why it is not returning result

Comment: Debug it. Print out $files before that comparison and check do you get results as expected.

Comment: When i print $files it says ----> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\music\search.php on line 46
Array  AND when i print $count it gives 12

Comment: $files is an array. Use print_r() or similar to print it's value. And since it has 12 elements it's normal that it won't print out your "sorry..." message.